# Invocation of another JSP Page from a JSP page

Tags: jsp

I am very new in Ejb-JSP and with very few knowledge about it.I am already created a JSP page which invokes controller Servlet and the servlet invokes EJB. Structure is Like **JSP -> Servlet -> EJB(returns result) -> Servlet -> output**. Now, I want to include a new JSP page which invokes our old JSP page means we want, **New JSP -> JSP -> Servlet -> EJB(returns result) -> Servlet -> output** structure. Can anybody help me, how can I call our old JSP page from new JSP page. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use JSP action `<jsp:forward>` and `<jsp:include>` in JSP page.

```
<jsp:forward page="/main.jsp" />
```

Bookmark or download Java EE Tutorials - [Java EE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajc.html) and [Java EE6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html)